# Replace List in Model vs. Add/Remove Items from List in Model

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Cart {
    static hasMany = [list: Fruit]
}
```

Say we made a domain in Grails with a hasMany relationship with another model. So in our service, if we want to update the list for an object, is it better to replace the entire list with a new list, or is it better to individually add/remove the items from the list?

Comment: You don't define what "better" means to you. What concerns are you trying to address. What's better for you may not be better for someone else if you have different concerns.

Comment: It is recommended to use `addTo*()` and `removeFrom*()` methods for your collections.

Comment: Not sure how to describe "better" here. Like if we commit the changes in the database, would setting the list property to an entirely new list cause problems? 
Would adding/removing items from the domain's list property take too long the more items are changed in the list?

Comment: @injecteer That is an option we're considering, but like I said, wouldn't that take longer since we need check the new list against the old list?

Comment: @AbrahamMiguelEspiritu that should be easy enough for you to measure and see which is faster in your particular situation. There are far too many variables (e.g. db speed, size of list, cache settings, etc.) to say which is going to perform better for you. You'll have to measure it for yourself.